# Transfering rotation to translation in most precise way?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, transmission

i am trying to make a very precise machine which will use a very precise linear encoder (nm range) and very precise servo motor. I want to use servo motor rotation to precisely move a "thing" in translation (i need 0,5 micron precision at least. What transfer would you recommend for this kinda of problem?
I was thinking rack and pinion option with gear translation for precision. But I am worried that big speed and tolerance of gears could be a problem?
Thanks

Comment: typically you'd buy a laboratory type linear stage for that, unless you know what you're doing

Comment: JWST mirror actuator ... https://youtu.be/5MxH1sfJLBQ?si=OK3AC2qjUuT7g_WY